# Open test format?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, standards

Are there any attempts at standardizing a cross-language test format?

For example, [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) is a spec for standardizing Markdown™ which is expected to be implemented in many different languages. It would be great to be able to test every implementation against the same set of tests.

They've included [this file](https://github.com/jgm/stmd/blob/master/spec.txt) in the official implementation which is already being [tapped into by a PHP implementation](https://github.com/colinodell/commonmark-php/blob/master/tests/SpecTest.php#L64) but it doesn't appear to be in any kind of standard format.

Are there any attempts at developing a format for tests? Where each test could have a name, maybe a short description, input, and expected output? Maybe even support for multiple arguments. It should either be easily parseable in any language, or should have parsing implementations ready-made in each language.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean by "cross-language test format" a testing-related language that can be interpreted/compiled into different languages there is the [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin) language used in [Behavior-driven_development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) that basically consists of

- given
- when
- then

in you markdown example you can write

- given a markdowninterpreter m
- when m gets "*hello world*"
- then m should output "*hello world*"

there are implementations for many languages for gherkin. i.e.

- [Behat](https://github.com/Behat/Gherkin) for php
- [specflow](http://www.specflow.org/) for dotnet

Comment: Oh! I've looked briefly at Behat and I've heard about Cucumber, but I didn't know they shared the same test format. They's cool!